# How to create Custom key-space-events on redis

Tags: redis, stream, touch, redisson

I am using Redisson Library and want to create an ObjectListner implementation using key-space-event for streams TOUCH operation.
How can I add custom Listener ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Events for TOUCH operation isn't supported by Redis